# Create custom prefix color util

Tags: tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind v3.1.7

I'm trying to style SVG stop-color with Tailwind. I want to be able to use classes like `stop-color-red-500` - the prefix should be `stop-color-` and then suffix is standard tailwind color. I tried this in my `tailwind.config.js` however it's not working, any ideas?

```
module.exports = {
  ...

  theme: {
    ...

    extend: {
      ...

      stopColor: theme => theme('colors')
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to look at creating [a dynamic utility plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#dynamic-utilities) like:

```js
// In non-CDN code, use:
// const { default: flattenColorPalette } = require('tailwindcss/lib/util/flattenColorPalette');
const flattenColorPalette = (colors) =>
  Object.assign(
    {},
    ...Object.entries(colors ?? {}).flatMap(([color, values]) =>
      typeof values == 'object'
        ? Object.entries(flattenColorPalette(values)).map(([number, hex]) => ({
            [color + (number === 'DEFAULT' ? '' : `-${number}`)]: hex,
          }))
        : [{ [`${color}`]: values }]
    )
  )

tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      stopColor: ({ theme }) => theme('colors'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    tailwind.plugin(({ matchUtilities, theme }) => {
      matchUtilities(
        {
          'stop-color': value => ({
            stopColor: value,
          }),
        },
        {
          type: ['color'],
          values: flattenColorPalette(theme('colors')),
        }
      );
    }),
  ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<svg width="100" height="100">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="Gradient1">
      <stop class="stop-color-red-500" offset="0%" />
      <stop class="stop-color-green-500" offset="50%" />
      <stop class="stop-color-blue-500" offset="100%" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect fill="url(#Gradient1)" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
</svg>
```

> Use the `matchUtilities` function to register utilities that map to values defined in the user’s `theme` configuration

The first parameter should be an object. The keys are the prefix(es) for the class names. In this case, the key would be `stop-color` as per your desire for that as a prefix. The value for the `stop-color` key is a function that returns [postcss-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-js) JavaScript object syntax for the corresponding CSS that the class should apply. The parameter that this function is passed is the function corresponding to the dynamic part after the `stop-color` prefix of the class name, in this case, the color. We use `stopColor` in camel case for ease of use. postcss-js will automatically convert it to kebab case `stop-color`.

The second parameter passed to `matchUtilities()` is the descriptor for the utilities. We pass `type: ['color']` to let Tailwind know this set of classes expects `color` CSS values. This enables [arbitrary value](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values) support. For `values` we pass in a flat object dictionary of colors. This lets Tailwind know the full set of values for our class name set. We use `flattenColorPalette` to convert the variable depth object of `colors` permissible by Tailwind into a flat dictionary of class name suffixes as keys with CSS color values.

Comment: Oh wow!! Thanks for such an absolute amazing answer!! I wish I could up vote this 3x! Not only did it give an answer, it really teaches it deep!